# Geocoder will not return coordinates for class instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use the geocoder gem to apply latitude and longitude coordinates to to my CoffeeShops model, but I can't get the geocoder to return the coordinates.

When I attempt to save a new instance of the class with an address, it saves successfully to the database, but the geocoding information for both longitude and latitude is 'nil'.

I've tried bundle installing.
I've tried adding a timeout in geocoder.rb initializer
I've tried adding and removing address validation (presence: true) in the model

## My coffee shop model:

```
class CoffeeShop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reviews
  has_one :feature_set
  has_one :wifi_speed, through: :feature_sets

  validates :name, :address, presence: true
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :will_save_change_to_address?
end
```

## My address migration file:

```
class AddAddressToCoffeeShops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :coffee_shops, :address, :string
  end
end
```

## My coordinates migration file:

```
class AddCoordiantesToCoffeeShops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :coffee_shops, :latitude, :float
    add_column :coffee_shops, :longitude, :float
  end
end
```

## My coffee shop schema:

```
create_table "coffee_shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.string "address"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_coffee_shops_on_user_id"
  end
```

## My geocoder initializer

```
Geocoder.configure(
  # Geocoding options
  # timeout: 3,                 # geocoding service timeout (secs)
  # lookup: :nominatim,         # name of geocoding service (symbol)
  # ip_lookup: :ipinfo_io,      # name of IP address geocoding service (symbol)
  # language: :en,              # ISO-639 language code
  # use_https: false,           # use HTTPS for lookup requests? (if supported)
  # http_proxy: nil,            # HTTP proxy server (user:pass@host:port)
  # https_proxy: nil,           # HTTPS proxy server (user:pass@host:port)
  # api_key: nil,               # API key for geocoding service
  # cache: nil,                 # cache object (must respond to #[], #[]=, and #del)
  # cache_prefix: 'geocoder:',  # prefix (string) to use for all cache keys

  # Exceptions that should not be rescued by default
  # (if you want to implement custom error handling);
  # supports SocketError and Timeout::Error
  # always_raise: [],

  # Calculation options
  units: :km,                 # :km for kilometers or :mi for miles
  # distances: :linear          # :spherical or :linear
)
```

Comment: You probably need to pick a geocoding service you want to use - the Geocoder gem has to ask an external service to perform the actual geocoding.

Comment: @rud And by default it uses `nominatim` which is free for one request per second https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/README_API_GUIDE.md#nominatim-nominatim

Comment: @jonny Your setup seems correct, have you attempted debugging? For example what is the result when you execute `Geocoder.search("The tested address")` in the console; or what happens when you remove the `if` modifier in the after_validation callback?

Comment: @kluka Thanks for those suggestions.

Here's what I got initially when I execute that command:
"Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit)."

After this, I set the timeout to 3 in the geodocer initializer. 

I then tried again and was able to get some results. However, after trying a couple of different searches, I then got the following:
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
from /Users/jonny35/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock'

Comment: Well that means you have to fix your network setup, it is not an issue with the gecoder gem specifically. You should be able to search on Google with that error message :)

Comment: @kluka - Thanks, I think my internet was down when I was attempting your solution, so it was appearing not to work, but in fact, your solution was correct in identifying the issue, which was that neither of the addresses I was attempting to use in my seeds was being picked up with the openstreetmap/nominatim API.

When I tried Geocoder.search("new york"), it was working. After playing around with the address formats I managed to get it to work. Thanks for your help.